# How to make a toggle element close when clicking off it?

Tags: jquery, forms, popup

I have a group of classes which toggle. The code is this:

```
$(".form-btn").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle(0);
});
```

With the HTML as so:

```
        <div class="form-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="form-btn" id="buy-or-rent">Buy or Rent <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
            <div class="form-popup radio">
                <input id="check1" type="radio" name="buy-or-rent" value="To Buy">
                <label for="check1">To Buy</label>
                <input id="check2" type="radio" name="buy-or-rent" value="To Rent">
                <label for="check2">To Rent</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="form-btn" id="price">Price <i class="icon-caret-down"></i></div>
            <div class="form-popup">
                <input type="text" name="min-price" class="small price-input" placeholder="Min" /> to <input type="text" name="max-price" class="small price-input" placeholder="Max" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

This works fine but to close each toggle (form-popup) you must click again its respective form-btn. How can I change the jquery so that the form-popups close when you click anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code will make your `.form-popup` container disappear when you click anywhere on the document other then the actual pop-up itself.

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ 
    var formPopup = $(".form-popup");
    if (!formPopup.is(e.target) && formPopup.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('.formPopup').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the listener to your body so it closes whenever the user clicks outside:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
  $('.form-popup').hide();
});
```

This will close all the popups.

```
 $('body').on('click', ':not(.form-popup)', function(){
      $('.form-popup').hide();
    });
```

To avoid closing it if the click is in the popup, thank you matt smith for the heads up.

Comment: Would this not close the pop-up when the user clicks inside the pop-up too?

Comment: @MattSmith You are right, added a small condition to the selector :D